# What is a wheenydom?

Tags: meaning, terminology, technical

What is a wheenydom?  It's in the following context: (from a tech-related article)

> I know that PowerShell is cooler and such than TCSH and BASH, but this smells of Windows wheenydom to me.

Google gave me no results except where it's mentioned. Is it mistyped?

Comment: I tried to add the tag "tech-slang" but for some reason it replaces it with "terminology". Did I just find a bug in StackExchange? :-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure it should be "weenie-dom", as in "being a Windows Weenie", that is, someone who loves Windows, sings its praises, and belittles any alternatives regardless of their merits.

Comment: I know what a *wheelie-bin* is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that it's a mis-spelling of "weeniedom", which the ever-unreliable [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Weeniedom) defines as

> The domain and claimed territory of a self-appointed, omnipotent Weenie. This domain is often virtual and/or electronic. Its boundaries are often unknown to anyone except the Weenie.
>
> *"When "Joe" discovered I had gone into his sub-directory and worked on a spreadsheet without asking him first, he flipped out; I had inadvertently violated Weeniedom airspace"*.

In his case I would also defer to the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Weenie) definition number 6.1 of "weenie", which is

> (n) A person possessing significant technical expertise, without some of the theatrical connotations of "geek".
>
> *"He's a crypto weenie"*

Answer (score 1):

*Wheeny* is a misspelling. *Weenie* is a commonly used slang term with one meaning of (according to [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weenie)) *someone considered weak and unimportant,* and *-dom* is a suffix meaning *state or condition* (*-dom* can also mean *domain,* but that seems less appropriate to the context).  Thus *weeniedom* would be the state or condition of being someone weak or unimportant, which the speaker is associating with being a Windows OS fan.

The overall intent is to mock all those who take the given position as doing so for weak and unimportant reasons related to their affection for Windows.